# Verification using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have tried verification using stored procedure in SQL Server. But the stored procedure is not working.

I have a table `room`. I got the backup from room table as a room backup. I tried to verify in SQL Server using stored procedure, when `room` table record greater than room back up table record, so I need to rewrite the room backup table. I tried the following code but it's not working

```
CREATE PROC Sp_verify
AS
    IF (SELECT Count()
        FROM   Room) > (SELECT Count()
                        FROM   RoomBackup)
      BEGIN
          DELETE RoomBackup;

          INSERT INTO RoomBackup
                      (R_No,
                       R_Type,
                       R_stus,
                       AP_No,
                       P_Name,
                       R_Charge)
          SELECT R_No,
                 R_Type,
                 R_stus,
                 AP_No,
                 P_Name,
                 R_Charge
          FROM   Room;
      END
```

Please help me

Comment: Why's your procedure named with `Sp_` first of all?

Comment: Here is the reason why you should not prefix `SP_` in your stored procedures : **[Avoid using sp_ as a prefix for stored procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115(v=vs.100).aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

Modify procedure as given below:

```
IF ((SELECT Count(1)
        FROM   Room) > (SELECT Count(1)
                        FROM   RoomBackup))
      BEGIN
          DELETE RoomBackup;

          INSERT INTO RoomBackup
                      (R_No,
                       R_Type,
                       R_stus,
                       AP_No,
                       P_Name,
                       R_Charge)
          SELECT R_No,
                 R_Type,
                 R_stus,
                 AP_No,
                 P_Name,
                 R_Charge
          FROM   Room;
      END
```

`Count` function requires an argument. Also enclosing brackets were required for `if` clause